# Ng-repeat removal and Ng-style modification are not simultaneous

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-animate

I am trying to implement custom animations on a ng-repeat list. When an element is removed, all the elements that are below it go up.

This is done using a CSS animation on the transform attribute. On the beginning the element is not really removed from the ng-repeat list (there is an animation on the opacity attribute).

At one point, I should actually delete the element from the list. And, at the same time, I need to wind back the animation on the other elements, that have been artificially put too high.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="card in cards" ng-style="shouldBeUpped ? uppedStyle : ''">...</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$timeout(function() {
        $scope.shouldBeUpped = false;
        $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
    }, 1000);
```

The problem is that `$scope.cards.splice(index, 1);` and `$scope.shouldBeUpped = false;` are not simultaneous. There is a small noticeable delay (maybe 20 or 30 milliseconds), that looks very bad, because in the meantime there is a blank space on the screen (`$scope.shouldBeUpped = false;` is rendered before `$scope.cards.splice(index, 1);`).

Do you know what I can do please?

I heard about ng-leave and ng-move classes, but the examples I found on the web don't work for me... (I am using Angular 1.4).

Comment: Try to create simple plunk/fiddle.(Btw, calling apply in $timeout makes no sense. )

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is $timeout. You're adding 1s delay there.

I'm not sure how view could know about $scope.shouldBeUpped = false; earlier than $scope.cards.splice(index, 1); as all the changes are reflected when $scope.$apply()

Comment: I need a $timeout because I would like to wait for the end of the CSS animation before actually removing the element.

Comment: @Arnaud what triggers your animation? I thought $scope.shouldBeUpped = false; does that?